# Web component element click event listener not working

Tags: javascript, dom, web-component

I am creating a simple **Rock, Paper, Scissors** game.

I have decided to not use any framework, so I'm doing it completely in pure  JavaScript, using Web Components.

I've manage to do pretty much everything what I wanted, but there is a component ([ResultDisplay](https://github.com/vsambor/js-rock-paper-scissors/blob/master/src/components/ResultDisplay.js#L30)) on which for some reasons click events do not work on **replay** and **reset** buttons.

It's very strange, because I have a very similar component just near it ([StartCounter](https://github.com/vsambor/js-rock-paper-scissors/blob/master/src/components/StartCounter.js#L21)) which has a button click listener and there it works perfectly!

I don't understand what I'm missing...

```
_initEventListeners() {
  // This is always called.
  this.replayButton.addEventListener('click', this._onReplayClick.bind(this));
  this.resetButton.addEventListener('click', this._onResetClick.bind(this));
}

_onReplayClick() {
  // This is never called when I'm clicking on the button.
  this.triggerEvent('replay');
}
```

I cannot put the entire code here, it would be too hard to read. 

But you can find it all [here](https://github.com/vsambor/js-rock-paper-scissors) and even test it yourself with `npm run dev`

Any idea is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, you add the event listeners to the buttons inside the initial `<result-display>` content.

However, when you want to display the result of the first game, you call `createTemplate()` again, which recreates a new DOM in the `shadowRoot` with new buttons, with no event listeners attached to them.

You sould then call `_initEvenListeners()` again.

Comment: You are pointing to the right direction! When I set a new property of a component I call the `render()`... I have to find a solution to render only the inner stuff not the entire component. :-|